# multiprocessing pool.starmap not works for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

It's very frustrating to see that it doesn't work and that it doesn't get to print the first line of the function. I've tried everything.

```
def process_image(image_path, output_path, thumb, luto, log):
    print ("ssssssssssssssssssssss")
    image_name, image_ext = os.path.splitext(image_path)
    if image_ext.lower() == '.tif' or image_ext.lower() == '.tiff':
        logging.warning("tiff file not supported yet, continuing...")
        return
    else:
        try:
            im = Image.open(image_path)
        except IOError:
            logging.info(image_path + " not an image file, continuing...")
            return

        if (im.mode != 'RGB'):
            im = im.convert('RGB')

        if thumb > 0:
            new_dims = (int(im.size[0] * thumb / max(im.size)),int(im.size[1] * thumb / max(im.size)))
            im = im.resize(new_dims, Image.BICUBIC)
            image_ext = "_thumb" + image_ext

        im_array = np.asarray(im, dtype=np.float32) / 255
        luto.transform_trilinear(im_array, in_place=True)

        im_array = im_array * 255
        new_im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(im_array))
        lutname = luto.filename.replace(' ', '_')
        if output_path is None:
            new_im.save(image_name + '_' + lutname + image_ext,quality=95)
        else:
            new_im.save(output_path + os.path.basename(image_name) +'_' + lutname + image_ext, quality=95)
images_queue=[]
luts=[]

for z in lutito:
    images_queue.append(('./DSC0818.jpg', './', 0,CubeLUT(z), False))

with    Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    t=pool.starmap(process_image, images_queue)
    print (t)
```

THIS PART OF CODE NOT WORKS WITH pool.starmap

```
with Pool(processes=2, maxtasksperchild=20) as pool:
    print ("procesamos")
    pool.starmap(process_image, image_queue)
```

THIS change works welll but I dont understand why not works with pool.starmap.Not stop the function and not give me error

```
for x in todos_luts.lutito:
    luts_=CubeLUT(x)
    process_image("./DSC0818.jpg", " ", 0,luts_, False)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `p`, but `list.append` **returns** `None` (although it modifies the list).

Comment: p it is diferents luts that apply in the image. I put new code to see more clear, also not works.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem introduce all inside Main. I dont understand why works

```
def main():
    images_queue=[]
    luts=[]
    for z in lutito:
        images_queue.append(('./DSC0818.jpg', './', 0, CubeLUT(z) , False))

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        print ("procesamos")
        print (len(images_queue))
        pool.starmap(process_image, images_queue)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```